# Data Storage on Scratch Org

Tags: salesforcedx, file-storage, data-storage

Is 200 MB **data storage limit** for scratch orgs? Is it possible to increase it? I need 2 GB to fully test our app. I cannot find anything about this on Stack, SF Dev Forum.

Comment: Have you thought about deploying to a sandbox or production like org for testing?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you need to test your app "fully" on a scratch org? If you need a full set of data and test your app "fully", then scratch orgs are not the right candidate. You will need a partial copy or full copy sandbox for such scenario.

Comment: If I can find a way to use a scratch org why use a partial/full copy sandbox? I can automate the process of scratch org creation, test new features there with data and then scratch it after 30 days. Then start the process over.

The process of creating scratch orgs is much more convenient then full/partial sandboxes using dev hub.

I don't understand why anyone would downvote my question.

Comment: With all that you mentioned, you still don't need a full set of data. Not completely sure about your use case, but if you want to perform a full testing of your app, then scratch org definitely is not intended for that. It's more targeted towards feature builds as a disposable units. Yes you can utilize it for CI/CD process , regression testing but that does not require a huge amount of data. Btw - I didn't downvote your question. I have up-voted it to equalize.

Comment: I really appreciate your thoughts (and upvote) Jayant! I found that the 200 MB data storage limit in scratch orgs is a hard limit: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs.htm

Comment: I have added some more details on this topic as an answer, hope it helps. While Scratch Orgs can do certain things, but it shouldn't be expected to replace the different types of sandboxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extending the comments, and adding some more information.

As for your questions:

> Is 200 MB data storage limit for scratch orgs?

Yes. That's the [limit for data](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs.htm) for Scratch Orgs.

> Scratch orgs have these storage limits:
>
> 200 MB for data
>
> 50 MB for files

Then for:

> Is it possible to increase it? I need 2 GB to fully test our app

I am not aware that you can request to increase the data limit for Scratch Orgs. Even if there was I would then consider Scratch Orgs were not utilized for the purpose intended.

Scratch Orgs are targeted for feature *development* and to facilitate CI/CD process with automated testing. These are always disposable units. For all these things, you don't need *huge* set of data. From [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs.htm):

> The scratch org is a source-driven and disposable deployment of Salesforce code and metadata.
> ....
>
> Scratch orgs drive developer productivity and collaboration during the development process, and facilitate automated testing and continuous integration.

Then you shouldn't *fully test* your app in a Scratch Org. A full test signifies that you are performing UAT, Integration Testing, etc. at full scale. A good mention about this is on this [trailhead module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/sfdx_app_dev/sfdx_app_dev_setup_dx) (emphasis mine):

> **Do Scratch Orgs Replace Sandboxes?**
>
> **No**. Scratch orgs aren’t meant to be replications of sandboxes or production orgs. Due to their ephemeral nature (and maximum 30-day lifespan), **scratch orgs are perfect for developing a new feature or customization or package. And they work great for unit testing and continuous integration**. **Sandboxes**, which contain all the metadata of your production org, **are still necessary for final user-acceptance testing, continuous delivery, and staging**.

In summary, you should not be really looking to fully test your application in Scratch Orgs.

Comment: What if we create an scratch org with "Enterprise Edition" in our scratch definition file, that also has same limits ?

Comment: @Anshul The docs does not categorize based on editions. So I would assume it to be same for all editions.